# Get recipient name on view in laravel mail

Tags: laravel-5

I have a set of recipients. I am able to send mail to all of them. But how to get their name on the view. To be specific how to get $user value in my view(emails.test).

```
Mail::send('emails.test', ['data' => $data], function ($message) use ($data) {

        foreach($data['users'] as $user) {
            $message->to($user->email, $name = $user->firstName . ' ' . $user->lastName);
        }

        $message->subject('test');
    });
```

Is there any way to access $user value in my view? I can access $data in my view. $data['users'] is an array of users. I need particular/current User's name in the view.

My view(emails.test)

```
<div>Dear {{$user->firstName}},</div>
How are you?....
```

But user is undefined here.

Thanks in advance.

Debabrata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail)

> The send method accepts three arguments. First, the name of a view
>   that contains the e-mail message. Secondly, an array of data you wish
>   to pass to the view. Lastly, a Closure callback which receives a
>   message instance, allowing you to customize the recipients, subject,
>   and other aspects of the mail message

as you can see the second arguments its the data you send to the view

so in your view you can use the $data array just like you did inside the closure:

```
@foreach($data['users'] as $user) {
            {{$user->username}}
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Amir for your response.
I can access $data. Even I can access $data['users']. But how to access that particular user's name?
$data['users'] gives me the array of users. I need to show User's name on the view. 
Thanks

Comment: $user->username or whatever the username column name is in your db

Comment: oh after the edit I got it, what are you trying to do? if $data['users'] has 10 users, you want to send same mail to this 10 users, or different mail to each user?

Comment: same mail. But I need current user's name. Thanks.

Comment: so this 10 users will get email with 10 names on the mail? if yes than you cant acess $user without first looping the $data['users'] array look at my answer

Comment: but i am still pretty sure that you want something else, you want to send 10 emails to 10 different users with the name of the user in each mail so each user will get his name in the email and not other names

Comment: 10 users, same mail with their name in the mail. I think I need to send mail in a loop. This is not the correct way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: yes so you are doing it wrong you actually want to send different mail to each user(even if 1 letter is different than it's different mail), you need to loop at each user then inside the loop send the mail